# Multilanguage keyboard mapping files

Tags: software-rec, keyboard-layout, xkb

I would like to make a web page where the user chooses a language, and depending on the language, show a keyboard with all characters corresponding to that keyboard.

I've been told that Unix has everything already done for that.

Where should I look to find out all keyboards, with mappings, that my Linux supports?

I would like to create a Webpage that displays something like this:

[image: Keyboard layout]

What is the utility which could hep me to generate this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for an X environment, `xkbprint` looks like what you're looking for:

```
NAME
   xkbprint - print an XKB keyboard description

SYNOPSIS
   xkbprint [options] source [ output_file ]

DESCRIPTION
   The  xkbprint  command generates a printable or encapsulated PostScript
   description of the XKB keyboard description specified by  source.   The
   source  can be any compiled keymap (.xkm) file that includes a geometry
   description or an X display specification.
```

If you want to show it on the user's X display, then you'll also need to look at a PostScript viewer, such as `gs`.

Comment: I re-read the question, and you want it as a 'web page' - so you'll want `gs` to write a PNG or something.  Also easily done.

Comment: I want to have a keyboard with all 4 possible combinations that are in the configuration files of the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` directory. Using xkbprint like explained here http://askubuntu.com/questions/380052/how-to-use-xkbprint only prints keys and shift keys, never altgr combination keys. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Did you use `-nkg 2` option to `xkbprint` to make include more than one group shift?  I'm not sure whether altgr is a group shift in your layout, so it might not work for you.